# Trying to delete members via a listbox - how to call my delete function passing the member's id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

To list all my members, I simply run a function that runs a **SELECT** query (**mssql**) and lists all users by frst name / last name. I also fetch the user id there.

To delete a user, I have a delete button, which runs a delete function that runs a query such as

```
DELETE FROM members where id = @id
```

However, for the `@id`, I use the `SelectedIndex`, which of course is not always equal to the user ID. I'd like to pass the user ID to my delete function as a param but I'm not sure how.

I tried creating a hidden textBox for each member, with their ID in it, but it failed and doesn't seem like the best way to do it even if I succeed with that technique.

How would you go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you populate the `ListBox`, place ID of the member as the `value` of the `ListBox` items using the `DataValueField` property.

```
listbox.DataValueField = "id";
```

Then you'll be able to use `SelectedValue` to get ID of the member to delete.

```
var memberId = Convert.ToInt32(listbox.SelectedValue);
```